# Debugging APK with Native Library

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, native, native-code

I have an APK generated from eclipse which contains a native library packaged inside the APK.
I start a service when BOOT_COMPLETED is received. Normal version of SO file and APK runs fine.

I had setup the debug environment and tried to debug this app and native code.

Now the problem is if i install this through `ADB install my.pack.age.app` it gets copied to `data/app` and then i dont get the `BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent.

When i manually put this apk to `system/app` folder i get unsatisfied linker error as library not found. It is searching in path `data/data/my.pack.age.app/lib`.

I have the debug version of native library generated with `gdbserver` file and other `gdb.setup` and other things are setup properly for debugging.

**How can i debug this apk while installing in the `/system/app` folder?**

`PS: Modifying the Packages.xml and packages.list by hand and changing the path of native library is not in my option as it would require every time to modify that file & may get corrupt installation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, For system APKs that are bundled with Device from OEM,
You have to put the library in System/lib folder for all the APk in system/app folder.
I was putting it packaged inside the APK.